# util.date contructor returns null

Tags: java

I have this date `Tue Dec 31 08:08:03 UTC 2019` as string.

I'm using `new Date(String string)` to parse it as `Java.Util.Date`, but it gives me null.

How this can be resolved ?

```
public static Date dateFromString(String date)
    {

        return new Date(date);
     }
```

I even tried this, not doesn't work :

```
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd HH:mm:ss a z");
        try {
            System.out.println(df.parse(date));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
```

Comment: Can you share you code please?

Comment: @SandeepKumar added

Comment: Suggest adding a breakpoint in the Date constructor you've used and work your way through to find why the value is set to null.

Comment: You should also say what input you're passing to the function

Comment: from here it only means you are not passing the input to the method hence: NPE.

Comment: What is the value of date when you debug ?

Comment: I dont have a pc, using online compiler of tutorials point

Comment: You have not imported as online compiler doesn't automatically imports libs.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Z43.png, take a look here, the problem was - **online compiler doesn't tell you that you are using deprecated method**

Comment: Note that the `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes are **outdated**. You should use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a date formatter like that:

```
public static Date dateFromString(String date) throws Exception
{
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
  return sdf.parse(date);
}
```